# Life and Death of Trees

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, polyglot

### The Challenge

Write a program that takes an integer *N* as input, and outputs the stage of life or death that a tree is currently in. *N* will always be between 0 and 10.

**The Stages of Life and Death**

- **Life:** To draw a stage of life, simply draw a base of size *N*, consisting of `^` characters, then move up and substract 2 from *N*, if the result is greater than 0, and draw a line of `^` characters again, again with the size of the new *N*. Repeat while *N* is larger than 0. To finish off, place either a single `|` character if the startoff value of *N* is odd, or two `||` characters if it was even.
  Example: `N = 5`

  ```
    ^
   ^^^
  ^^^^^
    |
  ```

  Note that if *N* = 0, only the stem will be drawn, without the leaves (`^`) on them.
- **Death:** This is roughly the same as *Life*, except that the base is *10 - N*, you use `M` instead of `^` and you add 2 to *N* and redraw the lines with the same procedure  as above, but this time you add 2 to *N* while it is smaller or equal to 10.
  Example: `N = 3`

  ```
     M
    MMM
   MMMMM
  MMMMMMM
     |
  ```

### The Goal

Your program has to run in 2 different languages both have to take a input *N*. The first language has to output the **life** stage of a tree according to *N*, the second language has to output the **death** stage.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes that meets all the requirements wins.
- The code has to run in 2 different languages. Yes, Python 2 and Python 3 *are different languages*.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Trailing newlines or spaces are allowed.

### Test Cases

Input: `N = 1`

**First language (life):**

```
 ^
 |
```

**Second language (death):**

```
    M
   MMM
  MMMMM
 MMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMM
    |
```

---

Input: `N = 10`

**First language (life):**

```
    ^^
   ^^^^
  ^^^^^^
 ^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^
    ||
```

**Second language (death):**

```
||
```

---

**Good luck coding!**

Comment: can there be trailing/leading newlines or trailing spaces?

Comment: @dzaima Yes, i'll edit that in.

Answer (score 10):

## Dyalog APL / SOGL, <s>70</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
0000000: 7b0d 04eb c0fd 5832 5c49 e32a 2e4c ac20  {.....X2\I.*.L. 
0000010: 4d2a 5b3a 836b 6b7d 01ea 500d 9b31 a90f  M*[:.kk}..P..1..
0000020: 7b0f c285 c8c7 b932 c00e f8b1 c70f 7db0  {......2......}.
0000030: 32c2 8531 9c85 80b2 b50f aa32 f97d       2..1.......2.}
```

#### Interpreted in [the classic Dyalog APL encoding](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/59183): - life: (contains unprintables), expects `⎕IO←1`

```apl
{' ^|⎕X2I┤z.L?pMzÅÏÏ}ûP'[1+⍵{⍵,⍨⌽⍉(2|⍺)↓⍉⍵}↑2,⍨1/⍨¨⍳⌈⍵÷2]}
```

[TryAPL here!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%20%u2190%20%7B%27%20%5E%7C%u2395X2%05I%u2524z.L%3FpMz%04%03%C5%CF%CF%FBP%27%5B1+%u2375%7B%u2375%2C%u2368%u233D%u2349%282%7C%u237A%29%u2193%u2349%u2375%7D%u21912%2C%u23681/%u2368%A8%u2373%u2308%u2375%F72%5D%7D%20%u22C4%20f%203&run)

```
{' ^|..'[1+⍵{⍵,⍨⌽⍉(2|⍺)↓⍉⍵}↑2,⍨1/⍨¨⍳⌈⍵÷2]}

         1+      add 1 to every value
 ' ^|..'[  ....] index the array getten below into " ^|.." with SOGLs code never being indexed in


⍵{..}↑2,⍨1/⍨¨⍳⌈⍵÷2

          1/⍨¨      replace each with that many 1s
              ⍳     the first ... numbers
               ⌈      ceiling of
                ⍵÷2     the right argument divided by 2
       2,⍨          append 2
      ↑             mix; convert to a 2D array, padding with zeroes
⍵{..}               execute that function with the arguments ⍵ - my right argument and the result of above


   {⍵,⍨⌽⍉(2|⍺)↓⍉⍵}  helper function
    ⍵,⍨             append the right arg to
               ⍉⍵     the right arg transposed
              ↓       without the first ... rows
         (2|⍺)          remainder of left arg ÷ 2
       ⌽⍉             transposed and reversed
```

#### Interpreted in [SOGLs encoding](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md) - death:

```
{∑⁴╝υ”X2\I┐*.Lκ M*[:≥kk}¹╚P∑Β1Ι»{»φ√ωΩΡ2υ«⌠ΝΩ»}μ2φ√1β√↓νΟ»ι2⌡}
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTdCJXUyMjExJXUyMDc0JXUyNTVEJXUwM0M1JXUyMDFEWDIlNUNJJXUyNTEwKi5MJXUwM0JBJTIwTSolNUIlM0EldTIyNjVrayU3RCVCOSV1MjU1QVAldTIyMTEldTAzOTIxJXUwMzk5JUJCJTdCJUJCJXUwM0M2JXUyMjFBJXUwM0M5JXUwM0E5JXUwM0ExMiV1MDNDNSVBQiV1MjMyMCV1MDM5RCV1MDNBOSVCQiU3RCV1MDNCQzIldTAzQzYldTIyMUExJXUwM0IyJXUyMjFBJXUyMTkzJXUwM0JEJXUwMzlGJUJCJXUwM0I5MiV1MjMyMSU3RA__,inputs=Mw__)

Explanation:

```
{∑⁴╝υ”X                         push "{∑⁴╝υ" and pop it - noop
       2\                       push input divides by 2
         I┐*                    get that many + 1 vertical bars
            .Lκ                 push 10-input
                M*              get that many "M"s as a string
                  [    }        while ToS isn't falsy (here: isn't "")
                   :              duplicate the string
                    ≥             put the duplicate at the stacks bottom
                     kk           remove the last 2 letters (does nothing when the string is empty)
                        ¹       wrap everything in an array
                         ╚      center horizontally
                          P     print that
                           ...  execute a bunch of random nonsense which luckily does nothing
```

This took way too long.. Golfing tips for the APL part are welcome, everything mostly should be applicable as long as it doesn't change anything before `ûP'`

You can load the file (after reversing `xxd`) in [SOGL](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/) by selecting the file in the `Browse...` dialog and then clicking `load SOGL codepage encoded file`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>119</s> <s>110</s> 109 bytes

```python
r=p='';n=1/2>0;b=(-1)**n*int(input())+10*n
while b>0:r=p+'^M'[n]*b+'\n'+r;b-=2;p+=' '
print(r+p[1:]+'||'[b:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc69CsIwFAXgPU8Rutz8UEwqOiSkb@DmVuuQGmhAbkNoUaHvHlt0PMN3zkmfeZywKcP0CC5XVVWySw7AotOHplXWO1ZrLgSKiDOLmJaZcS61EkheY3wG6ltlNiThfoEOe@El3BBktr52jU3SAQWS8s6zTJ02vYR1hc6bnpdt8V9zzUswhNLwDgPb7/At/BgAL1qRMzmR4xc) (Python 2, life)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc69CoMwFAXgPU8RXG5@kCZKOyTEN@jWzdohNqAg1xCUtuC7p0o7nuE758TPMsxY535@BpeKosjJRQdg0elT1SjrHSs1FwLFiAsbMa4L41xqJZC8hnEK1DfK7EjC4wotdsJLuCPIZH3pKhulAwokpoMnGVttOgnbBq03Hc/74r/mltZgCKXhHXp23OF7@DEAnrUiF3Im9Rc) (Python 3, death)

Comment: `b=int(input())` and then `if n:b=10-b` saves a byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) / [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 121 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 m=-1;n,c=(n,10-n,'^','M')[1/2>0::2];s=''
 while n>0:s=' '*m+c*n+'\n'+s;m+=1;n-=2
 return s+' '*m+'|'*(n%2or 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LCsMgFEXnWcWblKdRqTo0mB10Bf1MUkMC9SWooRS6dyt0eA@Hc/dPWTaytT7DDDMj7jqIXpmB5OQZSaMVSXygxAvyqznbUTtn70P2iB28l/UVgBprG7CPYupJ4I1Q5CEK3zLK2w5SKEciyOIv4Rd7Rie7JbC87mml0r5X2o/COK9G/wA) (Python 2)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNCsMgFIT3OcXblKfR0Gh3irlBT9CfTRqJ0LyIMZRC724tncXAN3xMfOd5pVMpj8mDZ8RNA4vrlCU5OkZS9R1JvKPEM/KLOuqhN0bf7OYQG3jN4TkB1a0yYLuIsSWBV0Kx2UW4etM53UCa8p4INvGX8IMto4NeE2heYgqUmWe/DhT3zHhNUf0X) (Python 3)

Comment: [116 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dc0xDoMgFAbg3VO8pXkgmAojht6gJ7B2sRpN6q8BTNOkd6es3/Id37TssDm/pplmAekqgh69gDZtA81P1nxn2ZurvbXO2aGLfvPMFX2W9T0RihZRYw3FD7CK3aY8E3dovK0oTOkMoKi23rhB8Y9rgYvdA1mZj7AilXbFcSYhZTbtHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/)/[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 128 bytes

```python
def f(n,a=1/2>0):
 m=[n,10-n][a];k=-~m%2+1
 for j in range(k,m+1,2):print(" "*((m-j)//2)+"^M"[a]*j)
 print(" "*((m-k)//2)+"|"*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctLCsIwEADQfU4xBIRMPqSJu0q8gScoFQI22oRMS@lGEK8eXbhx/9763B8LHVu7TQmSIB2Ds/7cYc@ghoG06wyNQxxPJZh3PXjlGKRlgwwzwRbpPomiq3LaY79uM@2CA5dCVJPRWo@KXy/8@2VGBv@g/MCLy4ItCYftAw) (Python 3)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctLCsIwEADQfU4xBIRMPqTJsiXewBOUCgEbbUOmJXQjiFePLty4f29/Ho@NfGu3OUESpGNw1p877BmUMJJ2naFpjNOQg3mXk1eOQdoqrLAQ1Ej3WWRdlNMe@70udAgOXApRzIrWelT8euHfL1dk8A/yD7y4zNiScNg@) (Python 2)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##JctBCoMwEEDRfU4xDBQySUST7pT0Bj2BWBBqWg0ZRdwUSq@epnT9399ex3Plc873KUCQbEZva3dpqBWQfM/GNhUP/Th00VefdHLaCgjrDgvMDPvIj0lGk7Q1jtptn/mQCKikTNVCde1I4@2K5VcLCfiD0uKvqSI1vlFFykFayl8)

Comment: [124 bytes](https://tio.run/##RctLCsIwEADQfU4xBIRMPqSJu0q8gScoFQI22oRMS@lGEK8eXen68dbn/ljo2NptSpAE6Ric9ecOewY1DKRdZ2gc4ngqwbzrwSvHIC0bZJgJtkj3SRRdldMe@3WbaReimozWesmBK3698O@WGRn8uPz5xWXBloTD9gE)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) / [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 308 bytes

```c
#define _\
"""
main(N,n,j,k){scanf("%d",&N);j=-~!(N%2);for(n=j;n<=N;n+=2){printf("%*c",(N-n)/2+1,94);for(k=n-1;k;k--)printf("^");puts("");}printf("%*c",++N/2,124);N%2?puts("|"):0;}
#define _"""
#define/*
N=10-input();j=[1,0][N%2]
for n in range(1,-~N,2):print(N-n)/2*" "+"M"*(n+j)
print~-N/2*" "+"|"*-~j
#*/_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LbsIwEEX3/gp3EJWfSmyxKa7VL6h/gFIUmQTFUaco0BWQX08dHpW6m9E9d@ZEvYtxHGfbummxppsPAgDkq2qRBYUqqY6fDrHChsF8C@o5cJe8Hp5YmFvumu@eoU8OX31wKL3lp33f4nGiRQTFgkZeWGnUy@JGdx61cZ3rtOYP9BO42/8cDwzycPl3QMpQWGVsbueHbzfqDHxZugv5k56U70shSPCm1C1mlk2yK6PK9Sq31yQLUKQt0r7CXc2M0kNQli@vL@@uAihIeAfBUCZOrtGgwyM4g9BDIjNRbMbR/AI)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/) / [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 308 bytes

```python
#define _\
"""
main(N,n,j,k){scanf("%d",&N);j=-~!(N%2);for(n=j;n<=N;n+=2){printf("%*c",(N-n)/2+1,94);for(k=n-1;k;k--)printf("^");puts("");}printf("%*c",++N/2,124);N%2?puts("|"):0;}
#define _"""
#define/*
N=10-input();j=[1,0][N%2]
for n in range(1,-~N,2):print(N-n)/2*" "+"M"*(n+j)
print~-N/2*" "+"|"*-~j
#*/_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7LTsMwEEX3/oowVZGfSmyxocbiC/APlFJFbQJ2xDRKwwK1za8Hpw@k7mZ0z5057W//tUMzjrNtVQessvU7AQDyXQakXqKMsmGH/abEmsJ8C/LRMxudGh6onxtm611H0UWLL85bFM6wQ9sF7Ceab0BSr5DlRmj5/HShG4dK28Y2SrEb@gHMtj/9nkIaTncHhPC5kdqkdnr4eqGOwBaFPZF/6Un5uuSceKcLFTCxdJJdalmslqm9Ikkgwyxg1pX4WVEt1eClYYvzy6srhwwEvAGnKCIj52hQ/hYcgashkhnP1@Oo/wA)